# How can we manipulate number of Jcheckboxes being selected?

Tags: java, swing, events, jcheckbox

I have a small program that uses the JCheckbox. I have to ensure that the user selects at most 3 out of 5. Is there a proper way of doing it using counters?

The JCheckBoxes are populated in a for loop. where only one JCheckbox has been declared, but different values are assigned to them and added to the JFrame inside the same for loop.

The loop has been used because of data retrieval from database.

Answer (score 3):

assume that your jcheckboxes are inside `JPanel`

you can use this function to get number of selected `JCheckBox`

```
public int getSelectedNumber(JPanel panel) {
    int numberOfSelected = 0;
    for (Component c : panel.getComponents()) {
        if (c instanceof JCheckBox) {
            numberOfSelected += ((JCheckBox) c).isSelected() ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }
    return numberOfSelected;
}
```

Comment: This just tells you the number selected. It doesn't prevent you from selecting to many.

Answer (score 1):

> I have to ensure that the user selects at most 3 out of 5. Is there a proper way of doing it using counters?

You don't want to use counters. That just tells you how many are selected and doesn't prevent you from selecting too many.

Instead before allowing a checkbox to be selected you should check to see how many are already selected.

For example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CheckBoxGroup
{
    private Set<GroupButtonModel> models = new HashSet<GroupButtonModel>();
    private int groupSize;

    public CheckBoxGroup(int groupSize)
    {
        this.groupSize = groupSize;
    }

    public void register(JCheckBox checkBox)
    {
        ButtonModel groupModel = new GroupButtonModel();
        groupModel.setSelected ( checkBox.getModel().isSelected() );
        checkBox.setModel( groupModel );
    }


    private class GroupButtonModel extends JToggleButton.ToggleButtonModel
    {
        @Override
        public void setSelected(boolean selected)
        {
            if (!selected)
            {
                models.remove( this );
                super.setSelected( selected );
                return;
            }

            //  Check number of currently selected check boxes

            if (models.size() == groupSize)
            {
                System.out.println("Only " + groupSize + " items can be selected");
            }
            else
            {
                models.add( this );
                super.setSelected( selected );
            }

        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        CheckBoxGroup group = new CheckBoxGroup(3);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox( String.valueOf(i) );
            panel.add( checkBox );
            group.register( checkBox );
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Check Box Group");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( panel );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```